# Is there a way in react native to have a permanent placeholder inside of a text input?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[I want the 'To' to be in the Textbox and stay there while user types.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/78BL3.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to display the additional 'To' into your input value, and then slice the resulting string to avoid getting the placeholder into your result.

A working example :

```js
class MyInput extends React.Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.state = {
   text: ''
  }
 }

 textChanged = event => {
  this.setState({ text: event.target.value.slice(5) })
 }

 render = () => <input type='text' value={'To : ' + this.state.text} onChange={this.textChanged}/>
}


ReactDOM.render(<MyInput />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

Thsi is the answer for a web React app, you may change the input to a `TextBox`

Comment: Thanks! that is exactly what I was trying to do! thank you so much!!