# add placeholder to input in react js

Tags: reactjs

I have an input field, in which I want to add in the placeholder ' tonnes' when the user enters a number. So this is what I came up with for that:

```
<input tabIndex={isBig ? "0" : "-1" } placeholder="in tonnes" value={plantDetail.co2ReleasedPerYear + ' tonnes'} onChange={(e) => setCO2(e.target.value)} className="specify-detail-inp"/>
```

But this adds in tonnes after each character. For example, if the user wants to enter 99, it shows up as '9 tonnes9 tonnes', whereas I want it to show up as '99 tonnes'. How can I fix this? I also tried slicing the text from the end as mentioned here -> [Is there a way in react native to have a permanent placeholder inside of a text input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54077314/is-there-a-way-in-react-native-to-have-a-permanent-placeholder-inside-of-a-text), but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing from

`onChange={(e) => setCO2(e.target.value)}`

To

`onChange={(e) => setCO2(e.target.value.replace(' tonnes', ''))}`

Could be one way to solve the problem, however i don't think its the best way. Best way in my honest opinion, would be to just have (tonnes) written in input label.

Comment: You will also need to fix for when `e.target.value` is not a string.

Comment: I would've preferred to have tonnes written in the label as well, but this is the requirement from the client ;-;